# Static struct initialization without designated initializers?

Tags: c++, c, static, visual-studio-2017, designated-initializer

The following designated initializer example is valid in Visual Studio 2019 with /std:c++latest, but I'm wondering how to accomplish the same thing without designated initializers in Visual Studio 2017.

I am using C++ and I realize there is an object-oriented way to do this but I am NOT asking how to recreate this in C++ using constructors. This makes the tagging for this question a bit messy, sorry for any confusion.

I'm also struggling with the terminology here. Just to confirm, is `&(struct Foo)` a compound literal? And this is achieving compile time static initialization? Could `constexpr` be used somehow here instead?

```
// Header
struct Foo
{
    void (*Bar)();
};

extern struct Foo *FooAPI;

// Source
static void Bar()
{

}

static struct Foo *FooAPI = &(struct Foo) { // Error: Expecting an expression
    .Bar = Bar
};
```

Comment: Does your question have to do anything with C? If not, please remove the tag.

Comment: In a way, yes it does.

Comment: `.Bar = Bar;` --> `.Bar = Bar`.  Also: `void *(Bar)();` --> `void (*Bar)();`

Comment: C and C++ are two *very* different languages, so please don't tag both languages. The code you show is not valid C++ code, because yes it does indeed use compound literals.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ```
> struct Foo
> {
>     void *(Bar)();
> };
> ```

`Foo::Bar` is a member function that returns `void*`. C doesn't have member functions, so this would be ill-formed in C.

> ```
> {
>     .Bar = Bar;
> }
> ```

This is ill-formed in both languages. You may not put semicolon there. Solution: Remove the semicolon. Optionally replace with a comma.

Besides, `Foo::Bar` is a member function so you cannot provide an initialiser for it. You may have intended `Foo::Bar` to be a pointer to function that returns `void`. The syntax for that would be:

```
struct Foo
{
    void (*Bar)();
};
// or nicer way:
struct Foo
{
    using Fun = void();
    Fun* Bar;
};
```

> ```
> extern struct Foo *FooAPI;
> static struct Foo *FooAPI =
> ```

A variable that was declared `extern` may not be redeclared `static`. Solution: Remove `static`.

> Just to confirm, is `&(struct Foo)` a compound literal?

`(struct Foo) { ... }` is a compound literal. The unary & is the addressof operator and the compound literal is the operand in this case.

> Static struct initialization without designated initializers?

Simply remove the designator so that initialisers apply to members in their declaration order. If the initialisers were not in the declaration order of members, then the initialisers must be re-ordered. In your case:

```
{
    .Bar = Bar,
}
// becomes ->
{
    /*.Bar =*/ Bar,
}
```

> I am using C++

There are no compound literals in C++. They are a C feature (since C99).

To rewrite it in C++, you need to use a named variable:

```
static Foo foo {
    Bar,
};
Foo *FooAPI = &foo;
```